# Merge column within same data frame

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame, looking like this:

```
df =  
A    B    C    D    E     F
1    NA   NA   10.2 8.9   abc
2    NA   NA   65.1 7.6   def
3    76.1 10.1 NA   NA    ghi
4    10.1 10.4 NA   NA    jkl
5    NA   NA   NA   NA    mno
```

In the end, I need it to look like this:

```
df = 
A    B    C    F   
1    10.2 8.9  abc
2    65.1 7.6  def
3    76.1 10.1 ghi
4    10.1 10.4 jkl
5    NA   NA   mno
```

All `NA` in `C` and `D` need to be replaced with the values from `D` and `E`, if they have a value! All the other columns need to be kept!

Comment: @akrun thanks for pointing that typo out!

Comment: Another option using `max.col` `indx <- max.col(!is.na(df[2:5]), 'first');df[2:3] <- df[2:5][cbind(1:nrow(df), c(indx, indx+1))];df[c(1:3,6)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` works really well in these situations.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, B = ifelse(is.na(B), D, B),
           C = ifelse(is.na(C), E, C))
```

Comment: Oops.  That last `D` should be `C`.  but otherwise I think it's correct.  I'm running it again.

Comment: The edit described above returns the correct value.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: neat. I like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, this should be both fast and scalable (to many columns):

```
foo <- function(x, y) pmax(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)
cols1 = c("B", "C")
cols2 = c("D", "E")

df[, cols1] = with(df, Map(foo, mget(cols1), mget(cols2)))
df = df[, !(names(df) %in% cols2), drop = FALSE]
```

or the same concept using `data.table v1.9.5` - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, (cols1) := Map(foo, mget(cols1), mget(cols2))][, (cols2) := NULL]
```

---

The idea is quite straightforward. Using `pmax` with `na.rm=TRUE` on each column pair, one at a time, using `Map()`.